# Rails view templates in subdirectories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, template-engine

Is it possible to make rails automatically look in certain sub-directories for a view-template?

I have different formats on my page (html, iphone, android, js and so on..) and the views directories are starting to be a real mess. I would like rails to automatically look for templates in `/html` `/iphone` and so on and fall back to the normal directory if it can't find it. So for example, if the format is `iphone`, it will first look in `/views/users/iphone/index.iphone.haml` and if it can't find it, it will look for `/views/users/index.iphone.haml`.

Comment: I don't know any automatic way to do that yet but you can render whatever view you want in whatever folder you desire.

Comment: Yes, I know, but it would be really nice if there where a way to make it automatic : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.axehomeyg.com/2009/06/10/view-path-manipulation-for-rails-with-aop/

Yes you can.